# SQLITE3 selecting row matching multiple values from same column

Tags: sqlite

I use SQLITE3 for my DB,i have 3 table: Doc table (id,name,date),tag table (id,name,count) and the relation table (id_doc, id_tag) that connect doc and tag table (many to many relation). Now i'm stuck on a query: i want to select the id of document related to tag 1,2 and 3 but i can't figure out how to do this.
anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use aggregation and `having`.  Something like this:

```
select id_doc
from relation r
where id_tag in (1, 2, 3)
group by id_doc
having count(*) = 3;
```